# Can't make any change of hosts file on Mac OS ventura

Tags: mac, unlock, hosts

Ask for support!

I plan to add some records into hosts file under /etc/hosts. but when I try to change the file, I got error. unable to write a readonly file.

I even use the root account to try to change it, still failed. below is the file

```
sh-3.2# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),1(daemon),2(kmem),3(sys),4(tty),5(operator),8(procview),9(procmod),12(everyone),20(staff),29(certusers),61(localaccounts),80(admin),703(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),400(com.apple.access_remote_ae),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
sh-3.2# ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  688 10 25 08:19 /etc/hosts
sh-3.2#
```

I try to change the permission of this file, still failed.

```
sh-3.2# chmod 777 hosts
chmod: Unable to change file mode on hosts: Operation not permitted
```

and after I disable SIP, still failed.

However when I try to change other files in same folder(/etc), will work. only hosts file didn't work.

anyone can help me? great thanks!

Comment: Works here, even without disabling SIP. Can you run `ls -le@Od /etc/hosts /private/etc` and add the result to the question?

Comment: Don't enable the root user. Try giving Terminal Full Disk Access. Or: Do you have BBEdit? Try opening it with that.

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
chflags nouchg /path/folder/
```

From https://superuser.com/a/1666415:

> The nouchg keyword instructs chflags to turn off the user immutable file flag, thereby unlocking the file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening it in the terminal via `sudo nano /etc/hosts`?
You could also try with [Hosts.prefsPane](https://github.com/specialunderwear/Hosts.prefpane).

Comment: What is Hosts.prefPane?

Comment: https://github.com/specialunderwear/Hosts.prefpane

Comment: Does this still work in Ventura?

Comment: I don't know, bacause I0m with Big Sur, I think it could. Did you try simply copying the file on desk, editing it and then past is on the original onel? This works for me'

Comment: I didn't try anything, was just wondering because Apple reworked a lot of things for PrefPanes in Ventura and I didn't find anything about on on the Github page. But other PrefPanes seem to still work, so this one probably does as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the finder on protected files, right-click then select 'get info' and then click the lock in the very bottom right corner, it will ask for password. then You can scroll down and add users and change their permissions to whatever.

Works absolutely everytime for me on Ventura 13.4